# Cannot place a resource inside a ContentControl

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

This XAML does not work in Windows Store apps:

```
<ContentControl Grid.Column="1" Content="{StaticResource AddUserStep1Control}" />
```

Where the user control is loaded as a resource in the `App.xaml` like so:

```
<featuresUsers:BoyGirlPickerUserControl x:Key="AddUserStep1Control" />
```

And the control looks like this:

```
<UserControl>

.. namespace etc.

    <Grid>
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style TargetType="Button">
                <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10" />
                <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="96" />
                <Setter Property="Padding" Value="50, 20" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>
        <StackPanel>
            <TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" FontSize="96" Margin="0,50,0,30">I am a...</TextBlock>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                <Button>Boy</Button>
                <Button>Girl</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </StackPanel>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

As I understand it, a `ContentControl` can contain anything. I was binding the `Content` property to the view-model and then getting the `UserControl` from the application resources and setting it on the view-model property but that gave another error which led me to try doing it all in XAML.

I was able to instantiate a `TextBlock` in code in the view-model and set it on the bound property and see that control and text in the UI, but not so with the `UserControl`.

Here's the error message:

> A first chance exception of type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.XamlParseException' occurred in
>   GlyphWriterStoreApp.exe
>
> WinRT information: Failed to assign to property
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentControl.Content' because the type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl' cannot be assigned to the type
>   'Object'. [Line: 55 Position: 45]
>
> Additional information: The text associated with this error code could
>   not be found.
>
> Failed to assign to property
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ContentControl.Content' because the type
>   'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.UserControl' cannot be assigned to the type
>   'Object'. [Line: 55 Position: 45]
>
> If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely
>   continued.

**Update 1**

So the problem is setting controls that are resources as the `Content`. I just tried with a `TextBlock` that is declared in `App.xaml` and that gives the same error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to be a known issue.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/silverlight/en-US/9076af75-07e2-40b4-8890-6ea546d1e9de/cant-use-staticresource-as-content-of-contentcontrol

That's odd because even loading the resource in code, which yields an instance of whatever control, doesn't work, whereas instantiating the control in code does work even though they're the same.

They're just object references. Very odd. Looks like I'll have to dynamically instantiate my control types at runtime or use a template selector.